# Prevent Scrollbar from overflow - CSS

Tags: css, layout, scrollbar

Ok, so what I mean is better represented with this image-

[image]

I want that scrollbar to ***not appear off the container.*** Because of the `border-radius`, the scrollbar appears to go beyond the container's dimensions.

One solution that I figured out is to make the container `overflow: hidden` and use another scrollable `div` inside it, with some `padding` applied to the scrollable div.

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to affect the scrollbar, even if I set `box-sizing: content-box`.

[image]

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by using `margin` for the scrollable container instead of `padding`. Don't know why I didn't think of it before :-|

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to hide both the horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

```
body { 
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */ 
}

body { 
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */ 
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */ 
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */ 
.example::-webkit-scrollbar { }
```